# maven compliation BUILD FAILURE

Tags: apache2

good day

im installing dspace 6.3 on ubuntu lts 18.04 but when im compiling maven package its says BUILD FAILURE. what may be the problem please help!!

the JDK is up to date and maven is up to date

thanks in advance

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.108 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-18T02:26:19-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/becsadspace). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Comment: *"Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory"*

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix. You just need to navigate to the dspace directory before running the mvn command.

I would assume from the above message it's in /home/becsadspace/dspace.

Comment: how do i go on about that?

Comment: sorry im new in ubuntu field

Comment: Change directory to dspace.

    $cd ~/dspace 

then just build as normal 

    $mvn clean ...

Comment: it is still giving me build Failure :(

Comment: even when im using $mvn clean under the dspace directory